# Cargar el contenido de un ID devuelve {messageTemplate}

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando cambiar las alertas de Streamlabs en Twitch utilizando javascript, pero resulta imposible. El código que estoy utilizando es este:

```
window.onload
var domElement = document.getElementById("alert-message");
var texto = domElement.innerHTML;
var falso = ""
var longitud = String(texto).length;

var caracteres = "-+*/|}{[]~\\\":;?/.><=+-_)(*&^%$#@!)}";

for(var i = 0; i < longitud; i++){
    falso += caracteres.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 37));
}
falso = String(falso);
domElement.innerHTML = falso
var i = 0;
function cambiar(){
    if(i <= longitud) {
        falso = texto.substr(0,i) + falso.substr(i);
        console.log(falso);
          domElement.innerHTML = falso;
      i++;
      setTimeout(cambiar, 50);
    }
};
// Esperar un segundo antes de iniciar
setTimeout(cambiar, 500);
```

El problema está en que al hacer el `document.getElementByID("alert-message");` lo que carga es `"{messageTemplate}"` y no el mensaje en sí, que debería ser, por ejemplo, `"Pepe nos está siguiendo"`.

Comment: Probablemente no se ha cargado todavía el DOM, porque `window.onload` por sí solo no tiene efecto alguno, en todo caso: `window.onload = function() { /* Aquí todo tu código actual */ };`

Comment: Funcionó tal y como decías. Hay que añadir también `setTimeout(window.onload, 0);`